# Excel VBA only add vaiable if not already in table

Tags: excel, vba

I think this should be easy but I can't find a way to do it. The VBA code currently adds all the file name in a folder to a table. I would like it to only add the values that are not already there, your help is greatly appreciated

```
Sub GetFileNames()
Dim xRow As Long
Dim xDirect$, xFname$, InitialFoldr$
Dim Tbl As ListObject
Dim NewRow As ListRow
InitialFoldr$ = "C:\Users\OfficeTech1\Desktop\GetFileNamesEx\2015 PO#s\"
Set Tbl = Range("Table2").ListObject
xDirect$ = InitialFoldr$
xFname$ = Dir(xDirect$, 7)
Do While xFname$ <> ""
Set NewRow = Tbl.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
NewRow.Range(1, 1) = xFname$
xFname$ = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd personally recommend against looping over the entire table as that could begin to take a long time, especially as the table grows. Try searching for the item using the `.Find` method. See example below and modify it to suit your needs.

```
Sub DoesExist()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim bFnd As Boolean
    Dim itmToSearch As String

    itmToSearch = InputBox("Search")

    Set tbl = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")

    On Error Resume Next
        If tbl.Range.Find(itmToSearch) Is Nothing Then
            bFnd = False
            MsgBox ("Not Found")
            'Do stuff here
        Else
            bFnd = True
            MsgBox ("Found")
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a loop to go through all of the existing rows to check if the current file name is present. Something like the below:

```
Dim flg As Boolean
'...
Do While xFname$ <> ""
  flg = False
  For Each myRow In Tbl.ListRows
    If myRow.Range(1, 1).Value = xFname$ Then flg = True
  Next myRow
  If flg = False Then
    'your code to insert the row with xFname
  End If
Loop
```

I haven't tested this particular code block but the general principle is there.